# If $f_n$ is uniformly integrable, then $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int|f_n|I_{|f_n|>t} = 0$ for all $n$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Show that if $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a uniformly integrable family of functions, then $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int|f_n|I_{|f_n|>t} = 0$ for all $n$.

I feel like this should fall right out of the definition of uniform integrability, but it's not coming to me for some reason.

The definition of uniform integrability I'm working with is;

$\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is uniformly integrable if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(A)<\delta$ then $\int_A|f_n|<\epsilon$, for all $f_n$.

It's not clear to me why I should be able to get $\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x)|>t\} \right)<\delta$ for *every* $n$.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotcha, and you probably want to show that the limit is $0$, uniformly in $n$, right? If you say "Show $\lim_{t\to \infty} F_n(t) = L$ for all $n$," where $F_n(t)$ is some expression involving $n$ and $t$, this usually means to demonstrate that the limit is $L$, "pointwise in $n$." You usually have to specify by saying "Show $\lim_{t\to \infty} F_n(t) = L$ uniformly in $n$," if you mean the convergence is uniform in $n$.

Comment: Sorry about editing my replies; I think our replies got thrown off while I was editing my comment.

Can you say a bit more on your comment "$\lim_{t\to\infty}F_n(t)=L$ uniformly in $n$". I understand that I'm trying to show that this works for all $n$, but it seems like I want to find some fixed $t_0$ so that $\mu(x:|f_n(x)|>t)<\delta$ for every $n$. I can't see why I could get the measure of such a set less than the same value of $\delta$ for every $n$ though.